# org.json JSONObject adding extra object to JSONObject while returning it from spring boot controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, org.json

I am returning org.json JSONObject from spring boot controller (1.5.16.RELEASE). I'm getting an extra map object in it.

My code-

```
@GetMapping(value = Constants.API_LOGIN)
    public Object login(@RequestParam String userName, @RequestParam String password) throws JSONException  {

        UserAuth userAuth = new UserAuth();
        UserAuth user = null;

        try {
            Preconditions.checkArgument(!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(userName), "empty UserName");
            Preconditions.checkArgument(!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(password), "empty password");

            userAuth.setUserName(userName);
            userAuth.setPassword(password);
            user = authService.checkAuth(userAuth);

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(ex.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(e.getMessage());
        }

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

        if (user != null) {
            json.put("status", true);
            json.put("message", "login success");
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(json);
        } else {
            json.put("status", false);
            json.put("message", "username or password doesnt match");
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body(json);
        }
    }
```

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20180813</version>
</dependency>
```

expected Json

```
 {
        "message": "login success",
        "status": true
 }
```

I'm getting JSON

```
{
    "map": {
        "message": "login success",
        "status": true
    }
}
```

I dont know why im getting extra map object in my JSONObject.

Comment: Can you please show your complete controller method..where you are returning Json object

Comment: have added full controller method @kj007

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that the default Springboot JSON serializer is Jackson and it does not know what to do with the `JSONObject` so it wraps it into a `Map<String, Object>` where the key is `map` and the value is your `JSONObject`. 
In you case, It would be lot simpler to just use a Map:

```
@GetMapping(value = Constants.API_LOGIN)
public ResponseEntity<Object> login(@RequestParam String userName, @RequestParam String password) throws JSONException  {
    .....
    Map<String, Object> json = new HashMap<>();
    json.put("status", true);
    json.put("message", "login success");
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(json);
}
```

Or I guess an alternative solution would be to simply return a String stick `json.toString` in the body

```
@GetMapping(value = Constants.API_LOGIN)
public String login(@RequestParam String userName, @RequestParam String password) throws JSONException  {
    ....
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    json.put("status", true);
    json.put("message", "login success");
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(json.toString());
}
```

Comment: @gowthamg Cool! Please upvote and accept the answer!